# How can I add custom button in UIImagePickerController popover

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

[image]How can I add custom button in `UIImagePickerController` popover when I am selecting image from gallery?

Comment: Can you please update question with design image in it ? Exactly what UI you want to build.

Comment: after i selected the image from gallery i need these buttons inside the imagepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. These are by default buttons provided by Apple for UIImagePickerViewController. So there is one property you have to use and property is `allowsEditing`. You have to set it as `YES`

So that after selecting photo from gallery or camera, those 2 buttons will be shown.

Code should be like:

```
-(void)openGallery {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)openCamera {
    BOOL isCameraPresent = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    if(isCameraPresent) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        // Add overlay view with custom button on it. Set frames to button as per your choice.
        UIView *viewOverlay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        Create and initialise your `UIButton` here
        [viewOverlay addSubview:YOUR_BUTTON_OBJECT];

        picker.cameraOverlayView = viewOverlay;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Camera not present");
    }
}
```

**YOU CAN ADD OVERLAY ONLY IF `sourceType` is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`**

Make sure that you have confirmed `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol in your view controller.

Call those actions on tap of button or action sheet actions as per your choice.

**NOTE: UI of popover of UIImagePickerController is dependent on iOS version of device.**

Comment: Thanks @Pushkraj, if i want to add one more button into these means, how can i proceed. That is my need.

Comment: no , i don't want add overlay when open camera , i need while opening image from gallery